# What is the meaning of 0o777 as value of mode of mkdir?

Tags: python, literals, octal

I would like to use `mkdir` in python.

It has a parameter `mode`, whose default value is `'0o777'`.

I know file mode `0777` in Linux. However I don't know what `o` between `0` and `777` is. What is it?

Comment: Nothing a quick tour through [the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/) would help you solve. And, you should already be able to *guess* what it means (especially if you understand what `0777` is for kind of number, and know about hexadecimal notation).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude would *not* help you solve (unless you're trying to denounce the Python docs)

Comment: @mkrieger1 Yes something like that... :)

Comment: Precise documentation link: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#oct

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is a Python friendly way of expressing file permissions, using octal numbers.

```
>>> 0o777
511
```

Comment: *- But... I still don't know what 'o' between '0' and '777' is. What is it?*

Comment: `o` signifies that the number is an octal number.

Comment: @hspandher: thank you for answering it. I will refer to python document for more detail later.

Comment: @mora Earlier versions of Python didn't use the "o", but that caused problems for some people who tried to interpret decimal numbers with leading zeroes. So it got changed.

Comment: for future readers: in 0o777 the `o` stands for "octal", like the `x` in 0xFF stands for "hexadecimal". In linux file permissions the interpreter assumes that the number given is in octal numbering